# Sql server 2008 r2 - redundant rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The first query

```
   --645 rows
    SELECT  *
            FROM    (
                      SELECT DISTINCT
                                cu.*,
                                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY cu.Id ) AS RowNum
                      FROM      Customers cu
                                LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerCategories cc
                                ON cc.CustomerId = cu.Id
                                LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerServices cs
                                 ON cs.CustomerId = cu.Id
                      WHERE     ( @FullName IS NULL
                                  OR cu.FullName LIKE @FullName
                                )
                                AND ( @CategoriesIdXml IS   NULL
                                      OR cc.CategoryId IN ( SELECT  *
                                                            FROM    @CategoriesList )
                                    )
                                AND ( @ServicesIdXml IS NULL
                                      OR cs.ServiceId IN ( SELECT   *
                                                           FROM     @ServicesList )
                                    ) 

                                    ) AS _
            WHERE   RowNum BETWEEN ( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1
                           AND     @PageIndex * @PageSize
```

The second query

```
 --41 rows
    SELECT  *
        FROM    (
                  SELECT DISTINCT
                            cu.*,
                            ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY cu.Id ) AS RowNum
                  FROM      Customers cu
                  --          LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerCategories cc
                  --          ON cc.CustomerId = cu.Id
                  --          LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerServices cs
                  --           ON cs.CustomerId = cu.Id
                  --WHERE     ( @FullName IS NULL
                  --            OR cu.FullName LIKE @FullName
                  --          )
                  --          AND ( @CategoriesIdXml IS   NULL
                  --                OR cc.CategoryId IN ( SELECT  *
                  --                                      FROM    @CategoriesList )
                  --              )
                  --          AND ( @ServicesIdXml IS NULL
                  --                OR cs.ServiceId IN ( SELECT   *
                  --                                     FROM     @ServicesList )
                  --              ) 

                                ) AS _
        WHERE   RowNum BETWEEN ( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1
                       AND     @PageIndex * @PageSize
```

The second query returns right result set (41 rows), but the first returns 645 rows which is wrong. But I use `DISTINCT` in both queries and I wonder why first returns too much rows.

How do I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ROW_NUMBER` is not right, use `DENSE_RANK` instead.

You can see difference here : [Difference between ROW_NUMBER, RANK and DENSE_RANK](http://mangalpardeshi.blogspot.com/2008/10/difference-between-rownumber-rank-and.html)

`ROW_NUMBER` will give you different number for the same Customer, and this is not what you want, you need the same value so that your distinct could work.

Comment: It's perhaps. RANK() function returns 41 rows, but the pagination doesn't work properly!

Comment: What have you tried ? Rank will screw your pagination but Dense_Rank must be the good one.

Comment: But dance_rank() works properly! It's good. Is it really happen because of  usage ROW_NUMBER instead of DENSE_RANK?

Comment: @Alex: ROW_NUMBER() is giving every one of the 645 rows a unique `rownum`, and **THEN** the DISTINCT is being applied.  The order of ROW_NUMBER() then DISTINCT matters completely here.

Answer (score 3):

The DISTINCT is being applied *after* the creation of the ROW_NUMBER()

As ROW_NUMBER() is different for every row, every row is unique by definition.  This means that you appear to have a few options.

**Apply the Distinct in one query, then wrap another around it for ROW_NUMBER()**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num
  FROM
  (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      cu.*
    FROM
      <your query>
  )
    AS raw_data
)
  AS ordered_data
WHERE
  RowNum BETWEEN ( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1
             AND   @PageIndex       * @PageSize
```

**Use GROUP BY instead of DISTINCT**

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT
    cu.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS row_num
  FROM
    <your query>
  GROUP BY
    cu.id,
    cu.field1,
    cu.field2,
    etc, etc
)
  AS ordered_data
WHERE
  RowNum BETWEEN ( @PageIndex - 1 ) * @PageSize + 1
             AND   @PageIndex       * @PageSize
```